# How to get information about pcap version and link-layer of pcap file using python?

Tags: python, pcap

I have to get information about lipcap version and link-layer of a pcap file.
So, I did code through Python. But, I don't know the python well.

My code is below:

```
import dpkt
import socket
import sys

f = open('filename')
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts, buf in pcap:
    print ts, len(buf)
```

Comment: Do you want to get the version of libpcap installed on the system, or the version of libpcap a file was created with?

Comment: I want to get the version of libcap a file I was created.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to get information about lipcap version and link-layer of a pcap file.

For the link-layer header type, from a quick look at the dpkt code there appears to be a `datalink` method for a `Reader`, which returns the link-layer header type, so try `pcap.datalink`.

As for the libpcap version:

> I want to get the version of libcap a file I was created.

Unfortunately, 1) not all pcap files are created with libpcap and 2) there's no place in pcap files to store the libpcap version (there's a version field, but it's used for the version number of the *file format*, not the *library*), so there is no way to get from a capture file the version of libpcap used when the file was created - that information isn't *in* the file, and it *can't* be in the file (no place to put it, and no guarantee that libpcap was at all involved in the creation of the file in the first place).